# NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to get Xcode's iphone simulator to display by nib after the launch screen, but I keep getting this error.

Full error:

2015-03-26 21:01:40.462 Hangman Jury[5278:476697] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'HangController''

Relevant code:
in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[HangController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HangController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Erroring line in main.m:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

HangController is a simple subclass of UIViewController

Things I've tried:
-Spelling "HangController" correctly
-Making sure View2.xib is included in Copy Bundle Resources
-I have not renamed anything outside of Xcode
-I'm not using storyboards and I have removed storyboard items from Info.plist
-My view is linked to the target in the Target Membership list

Thanks for your help

Comment: "Making sure View2.xib" - If you file is named `View2.xib` you should probably try `[[HangController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];`

Comment: Tried it, same result :/

Comment: Nevermind, that was right!  I was getting the same exception for a different reason afterwards.